# Using vectors in CUDA

Tags: cuda

How to use cudamemcpy for vectors in C++ ? my code works fine for arrays but vectors it doesnt seem to support. Any idea how to support vectors in CUDA?

Comment: Care to share some relevant code? Then we can see what you're doing (wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't just using the basic CUDA APIs.

If you want to use STL containers with CUDA, you should look at the [thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/) template library, which provides and STL like interface to the GPU and a number of useful GPU algorithms to operate on data within container types.